# Enforcing a fixed length string on C API

Tags: c

I'd like to enforce fixed length string to my API function. Therefore, I notify the client about this via the function signature.

Instead of a simple 'char *' string, I define  a struct with single field which is the string of fixed length as an input. this argument is an output argument where the client is responsible for.

here's a sample code describing what i did :

```
#define STR_LEN 64
struct buf {
    char str[STR_LEN];
}

void calc_str(struct buf * b);
```

Is this an acceptable way of enforcing the client using a fixed length string  argument ?

Comment: No, because `buf b; strcpy(b.str, "a");` is fine.

Comment: @JohnB, i didn't quite understood your point. can you elaborate please ?

Comment: You can fill `buf.str` with a string of less than 63 characters. Hence if you only want strings consisting of 63 characters to be passed, your approach is not suitable for achieving your goal.

Comment: @JohnB, as it mentioned in the question, this string is an output and the client is responsible to allocate it, but the API is responsible for the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @Ian's answer, you can provide an opaque structure in your API:

```
struct you_cant_see_inside_me;
```

Do not provide the internals of your struct in your API - keep the structure definition hidden:

In `api.h`:

```
struct you_cant_see_inside_me;
struct you_cant_see_inside_me *createStruct( const char *data );
freeStruct( struct you_cant_see_inside_me *s );
int yourAPIcall( struct you_cant_see_inside_me *s );
```

Inside your code, that you don't distribute:

```
struct you_cant_see_inside_me
{
    char data[ 64 ];
};

struct you_cant_see_inside_me *createStruct( const char *data )
{
    struct you_cant_see_inside_me *s = malloc( sizeof( *s ) );
    // copy data to your satisfaction here, return NULL if
    // you don't like what you've been passed - you can set
    // errno to EINVAL to indicate invalid arguments
    return( s );
}

freeStruct( struct you_cant_see_inside_me *s )
{
    free( s );
}
```

You still have the problem of rejecting inputs that don't meet your criteria somewhere.

Here's a link to a simple example:  http://c-faq.com/struct/sd1.html

Comment: thanks that's sounds great idea, but how do i let the client use the data in the struct after it was modified by the method "yourAPIcall". i think I also have a getter.

Comment: @Zohar81 - Yes.  You do have to provide another way to get the results.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is by

1. notifying the client if his/her call is successful or not by returning a `boolean`
2. indicates by the function declaration that he has to give an argument `varSize`

So, for example, in C you could do something like,

```
//gives char return, and varSize input, the output here would be *myStruct
char createStruct (MyStruct* myStruct, int varSize){
    if (varSize != STR_LEN)
        return 0; //zero indicating false
    //length is acceptable, do something else
    return 1; //return this when everything is okay
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i basically want to enforce the client providing a string with a fixed length, i don't want it to be a variable.

Comment: I see, then the solution I gave may not really be appropriate since it is not really an "enforcement" rigidly by the function. It is rather a rejection if one creates something with improper length. But in either case, the "correct" length has to be informed to the client, otherwise he cannot know. One way to inform him is by true/false, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can define a  macro and use fix length string.

the much easier way to define macro is define it in a header file and use a protector in it. say for example we have header test.h

If STR_LEN is not defined then it will be defined and if defined no multiple definition will occur while linking.

```
#ifndef STR_LEN
#define STR_LEN 64
#endif
```